# Tensorflow Memory Leak with tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess = sess_

Tags: image-processing, memory-management, tensorflow

I have built a convolutional network with dimensions of 1750 * 1750 but it is taking much more memory than it should, Using 27 Gigabytes on four test images.

It happened after I added in  tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess). Before, there wasn't a problem.

There is a lot of code so all of it can be found here: http://structml.github.io/Neural-Network-Prostate/

There shouldn't be any problem with my code, since I have checked it thoroughly and borrowed some of it from the CIFAR-10 Code.

What is the issue here? Is it my code or something with the Tensorflow library. Keep in mind that the input functions are copied over from the Google Cifar-10 examples.

Below is my main file which calls the queue runners.

```
 import Input
 import Process

 import tensorflow as tf

 def train():
     with tf.Session() as sess:
          images, labels = Process.inputs()

         forward_propgation_results = Process.forward_propagation(images)

         train_loss, cost = Process.error(forward_propgation_results, labels)

         init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(100):
        print(sess.run([train_loss, cost]))
        print(test)

 def main(argv = None):
     train()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
   tf.app.run()
```

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2942#event-699911869